# Help - DDOS Attack

Tags: ssh, ddos, csf

I am under a DDOS attack. I'm trying to locate the IP address that is making 1100+ connections, however, when running the following command, it shows a 1100+ connection, but the ip address column is blank. By the way, I'm using CSF firewall to block connections.

> netstat -anp |grep 'tcp\|udp' | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort
>   | uniq -c | sort -n

This is what it returns. Notice the blank column next to "1157".

```
      1    xxx.xx.xx.xxx
      1    xx.xxx.xxx.xx
      2    xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
      2    xx.xx.xxx.xxx
      3    xx.xxx.xxx.xx
     63    xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
   1157
```

How can I find that missing IP address?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless your netstat is completely different than mine, you have 1157 *listening* (not connected) IPv6 sockets.  These (shown as :::*) are the only ones that come out blank.  Run `netstat -anp` by itself and pick a few lines that don't have any of those IP addresses you found, and show us what you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

netstat is returning connections like this:

> udp        0      0 :::57817                    :::*

which, if piped into "cut -d: f1", will return a blank line.

that said, and apologies if this seems condecending, how do you know that you're being DDoS'd?